# using Wicket's PagingNavigator with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, wicket

Is there a way to link paging Navigator to Ajax? I'm confused on how to do this since PagingNavigator interacts with pagableListView under the hood.  So basically the Ajax action I'm looking for is for the pagableListView to be updated with PagingNavigator using Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was researching PagingNavigator and Ajax,  but I was looking for the wrong thing.

AjaxPagingNavigator is the answer.